# "This question is an exact duplicate of"

Tags: discussion

I noticed the following situation: 
There is a question:

[How can I get the size of a file in x86 assembly Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900448/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-x86-assembly-linux)

It got some answers (I answered as well), but later was marked as a full duplicate of

[Simple way to Get filesize in x86 Assembly Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899469/simple-way-to-get-filesize-in-x86-assembly-language), closed and boiler-plated with:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

The trick here is that the mentioned older question has **no answers at all**, only some comments.

So, isn't it better in this situation to mark the older question duplicate and to point the users to the question that actually has some decent answers?

P.S. The above questions are just the case, that led me post this question here. But this situation is pretty common in Stack Overflow and in my opinion needs some common solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that both questions were asked by the same user. This is a special case. Normally you can't use a question with no answers as the duplicate target.

What should happen is that the questions are merged - which I've done.

Comment: But how about the common case? Or even worse - both questions have some answers, but the duplicate target has lower quality or outdated answers?

Comment: @johnfound - If it's the same question from the same user the lower scoring one should be merged into the higher scoring one - but that doesn't always happen. I'd suggest flagging, but that's just making more work for me and my fellow mods ;)